# Is there a way to save CGAL::Linear_cell_complex_for_combinatorial_map as .off or .obj format?

Tags: c++, cgal

I have just implemented an algorithm that takes a surface mesh, tetrahedralizes it and saves the tetrahedralization data inside the CGAL data structure [`CGAL::Linear_cell_complex_for_combinatorial_map`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Linear_cell_complex/classCGAL_1_1Linear__cell__complex__for__combinatorial__map.html).

I'm new to using CGAL library and I would like to know if there is a way to write [`CGAL::Linear_cell_complex_for_combinatorial_map`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Linear_cell_complex/classCGAL_1_1Linear__cell__complex__for__combinatorial__map.html) data structure in `.obj`, `.off` or some other formats.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an undocumented function `write_off(lcc)` (cf [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/ed3503d2381842f837a8118a749ab380f889485b/Linear_cell_complex/include/CGAL/Linear_cell_complex_constructors.h#L299)).

In the off, when a face is shared by two volumes, the face is saved twice. Moreover, the output mesh is not a surface, and some tools (like meshlab) does not like such a mesh.

It is easy to modify the code of `write_off` to save only the surface of your volumic mesh. Contact me if you need such function.